# Performance of two 1:N grouping methods

Tags: java, sql

Let's say we have two tables in a 1:N relationship. Now let's say on the java side you wish to structure the result data as such:

```
class ParentDto {
    public Long id;
    public String someColumn;
    public List<ChildDto> children = new ArrayList<>();
}

class ChildDto {
    public Long id;
    public Long parentId;
    public String someColumn;
}
```

**IN THEORY**, is it faster to perform a single sql query like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PARENT_DTO 
    JOIN CHILD_DTO ON PARENT_DTO.ID = CHILD_DTO.PARENT_ID
```

and then perform a grouping operation like so on the java side

```
// assume that query is some api to run a query like jdbc that returns theortical type List<Row>
List<ParentDto> results = query(/* query above*/).stream()
    // assume that first value in row is ParentDto::id
    .collect(groupingBy(row -> (Long) row.get(0)))
    // after collect stream type is Map<Long, List<Row>>, whatever row type is from whatever api
    .values()
    .stream()
    // listOfGroupRows is just List<Row>
    .map(listOfGroupedRows -> {
        // assume that ParentDto constructor knows how to fetch values from first row 
        ParentDto rowValue = new ParentDto(listOfGroupedRows.get(0))
        // assume that ChildDto constructor knows how to fetch values from each row
        rowValue.children = listOfGroupedRows.stream()
            .map(row -> new ChildDto(row))
            .collect(toList())
    })
```

**OR** is it faster to just run two seperate queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM PARENT_DTO

SELECT *
FROM CHILD_DTO
```

and then perform a grouping operation like so on the java side:

```
Map<Long, List<ChildDto>> children = query(/* second query */).stream()
    .map(r -> new ChildDto(r))
    .collect(groupingBy(ChildDto::parentId));

List<ParentDto> results = query(/* first query */).stream()
    .map(r -> {
        ParentDto dto = new ParentDto(r);
        dto.children = children.get(dto.id);
        return dto;
    })
    .collect(toList());
```

The first method only requires one query to the database, but has a higher volume since the number of rows returns is n * m where n is the number of rows in the parent table and m is the number of rows in the child table. It also incurs a cost on the java side of 2(n * m) (one to group, one to convert each row).

The second method incurs two queries to the database, but has lower volume because the total rows returned is n + m and each row is smaller then each row of the original join query. The java performance is better because it is n + m as well (m to group children and n to process and initialize parents).

By this logic, I would always choose option two, but I don't have a lot of practical experience with actual sql servers. Are there any situations that a more seasoned individual would/should choose option 1? Is the cost of another submission to a database ever so much that it would outweigh the complexity difference of these operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not mean for this to be a Q&A style post, but after sleeping on it, I realized I made a faulty assumption. The different types of joins have different complexities. The complexity that I mentioned (n*m) is the memory and computation complexity of a CROSS join, where the result of the two sets is a power set of the original sets. My original join query was not a CROSS join, but an INNER join. This is, at worst, a max(n, m) in both memory complexity and computation complexity, but can be much less depending on how many rows in both tables do not associate to the other table in any way, (a parent_dto with no children is not in the result set). That is also only for a naive grouping solution, as there are many methods sql servers employ to radically improve joins like indexing operations.

So in summary, in practice for inner and left joins, method 1 has a lower complexity (max(m, n) vs. m + n) and It will resolve much faster on the sql side in practice because of indexing and other pre-calc and caching methods. The only difference would be a slight increase in network overhead (redundant normalized data).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, if you incorporate some of this into your answer, I'll delete this and accept yours

Answer (score 2):

If you were using an ORM framework like Hibernate, this would be taken care of automatically behind the scenes.  And, it would be using the first version, where the join happens on the database, rather than the second version.  The reason why the first version is preferable is that databases are designed to do things like joins very efficiently.  Java would probably be less efficient at doing the same join operation.  The only reason I even see why the second version might be more efficient is the latency of data going back to and from the database.  The second version might involve transferring less data.  But, I think the penalty for doing database operations in your Java code would outweigh this.